# How can I determine which dependency would cause a C++ compilation unit to be rebuilt?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msbuild, dependencies, include

I have a legacy C++ application with a deep graph of #includes. Changes to any header file often cause recompiles of seemingly unrelated source files.

The application is built using a Visual Studio 2005 solution (sln) file.

Can MSBUILD be invoked in a way that it reports which dependency(ies) are causing a source file to be recompiled?

Is there any other tool that might be able to help?

NOTE: I'm only looking for a tool to tell me why a file *would* be rebuilt, not some restrospective magic telling me why it *was* rebuilt.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this wholesale, but you can improve things by making sure that headers only include a minimal number of other headers (doing this during routine refactoring/code changes). Sometimes this involves splitting headers into additional logical components.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. There is so much to fix that I want to focus initially on our pain points, which is where the tooling needs to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dial up the verbosity to detailed or above (Tools>Options>Project>Build or /v:detailed) then MSBuild will log, just before it runs the compiler, exactly what header file or source file caused it to run the compiler.

Is that what you're asking for?

Dan/MSBuild

Comment: this is pretty much what I was asking for. If I can also tell MSBuild not to run the compiler, that would be better.

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility called [makedepend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makedepend). It is available on Unix platforms. On Window you can find a similar perl script [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/nasm/nasm-10/nasm/mkdep.pl).

I do not think MSBUILD takes care of dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need Include Finder (http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Include-Finder-Download-83403.html).

Comment: Patrick, all the links to download Include Finder seem to be broken. Do you have any other link to it?

Comment: You can find it here, but I don't know how much use it'll be: It's from 2003.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/includefinder.aspx

Comment: Yeah just tried it on a VS2008 project and it didn't even start.  Using directories, it crashed.  Oh well.